# Pagination: /tags/tag_name/?paged=2 gives a 404 error

Tags: pagination, rewrite-rules

I need to paginate an archive page. Pagination works perfectly fine for everything except tag/category archives. Basically if I use /tags/tag_name/?paged=2 it gives me a 404 error. But if I use /tags/tag_name/?page=2 it works fine. Unfortunately I need to use /tags/tag_name/?paged=2

I reckon it has to do with rewriting. These are the existing rules WP has:

```
tags/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$   index.php?tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2] post_tag
tags/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?tag=$matches[1]   post_tag
```

I have tried all the combinations of rewrite rules I could think of to make /tags/tag_name/?paged=2 work. No success. How can I make it work?

===

What I found out it is only ?paged=2 that gives me trouble. /tags/tag_name/?abc=2 doesn't give a 404. Makes no sense to me.

===

ok, so what I decided to do is unset $_GET['paged'] in functions.php and set it's value back in header.php. Then I changed all the code to avoid using WP's get_query_var. Works for now.

Comment: Why are you trying to create rewrite rules for tags, WordPress does that for you already.

Comment: Try one time to save permalink in admin side.May it fix issue.

Answer (score 1):

I change the pagination param from "paged" to "page" and works! Dont give 404 more =)

Comment: Can you explain what you did in more detail, and explain why it solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permalink structure work for me!!!
 look:

the permalink was like this in custome structure: /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

then i change it to: Day and name( just select de radio button) and it will look like this: /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

i tried and then it works!!!

Thanks to God!

God Bless You guys!
seya

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Blog pages show at most` in `settings->reading` . This solved the problem I had with pagination which is almost the same.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way is to insert in your *functions.php*:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['paged'] ) )
    $_GET['page'] = $_GET['paged'];
```

Comment: that too gives me a 404.

Comment: Can you paste the code of this file in the pastebin.com?